# Format for second drive in Linux Server and path to directory in second drive for PHP

Tags: linux, ubuntu, php, hard-drive

I'm working for an office in primary education and I'm setting up a local server with Ubuntu Server 20.04. I have some web applications written in PHP for this server. I am relatively new to Linux and I have two questions:

1. I have two hard drives, `dev/sda` 250GB where Ubuntu Server 20.04 is installed, and a second one `dev/sdb` 500GB. The second was preinstalled and formated as NTFS. I want to use the second as a file storage. Is it a problem that it is NTFS or should I format it as EXT4?
2. The root of my web applications is at `var/www`, but I want to upload the files with PHP's `move_uploaded_file` to directory `/uploads` at the second HDD `dev/sdb`. How can I provide the path to the script? Should it be an absolute or relative path?

Comment: Will this old system ever have that much data on it? It might be worth it for reliability to set up a 250GB RAID 1 and forget about the remaining space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If there is no specific reason to have the drive NTFS formated (and i honestly can't think of one) you should use a native Linux filesystem like ext4 or btrfs
2. if /dev/sdb is only used for the uploaded files you can just mount /dev/sdb to "/var/www/uploads", then build the absolute Path like this:

`$uploadDir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/uploads/"`

which will keep pointing to the correct path, even if the webservers document root changes

However, this will make your files in the "uploads" folder directly accessible via the webserver. If this is not what you want, you should use a folder outside of your webservers document root.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer
Let me see if I have got it right. I formated dev/sdb as ext4. Then I created a directory /uploads inside var/www/html/<site_directory>. After that, using webmin, I set "mount as" the directory var/www/html/<site_directory>/uploads. Now does this mean that I have assigned all the capacity of the partition of dev/sdb to directory /uploads??? Can I use as target path the /uploads directory and the files will upload to dev/sdb???
I don't mind if the files are directly accessible via the webserver because I want the other employees to have access to them

Comment: yes, that would be the way to do it, if you want the uploaded files accessible via the webserver. just to clarify: you did not assign any capacity to the "uploads/" folder. if you mount /dev/sdb to the "uploads/" folder you just make the filesystem on /dev/sdb accessible via the "uploads/" folder. you can unmount it anytime and mount it somewhere else.